# hyperref \TextFields in table with fieldname above field

Tags: hyperref, forms

I want to create a pdf file with fillable forms. As I dont have much experience with the hyperref package, Ive got a few problems to solve.

One in particular is about the position of multiple fields within an array like layout, but with the field name above the field itself (see example below).

```
\renewcommand*{\LayoutTextField}[2]{% label, field
    {\scriptsize#1} \vspace{2pt} \\ #2 %
}
\TextField[name=fieldA]{FieldA}
```

As I managed to set the field name above the field itself, with the shown `renewcommand`, this doesnt seem to work within a table, using multicolumns and multirows. Is there either a better way to place the name above or a different use of tables in this case? The first table in the example below shows Ho Id like to place this, the second table how I thought it might work.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\title{Headline: \hspace{3em} \TextField[name=fieldC, maxlen=7, width=4cm, charsize=24pt,color=red,align=1]{}}
\maketitle
    
\renewcommand*{\LayoutTextField}[2]{% label, field
    \vspace{-5pt}{\scriptsize#1}\vspace{2pt} \\ #2%
}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    C & D & \multirow{2}*{E} \\ 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{F} 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \TextField[name=C]{C} & \TextField[name=D]{D} & \multirow{2}*{\TextField[name=E]{E}} \\ 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\TextField[name=F]{F}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

If there is a better package to be used than hyperref I am happy to try that as well.
Cheers.

Comment: you could not print the label at all (`\renewcommand*{\LayoutTextField}[2]{#3}`, and then add the label text directly in another row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot place `\\` inside a table cell just like this, at least not in a normal one, because it denotes the end of the current table row in this context. You'd need to wrap it inside some kind of pararaph-aware box.

A simple way to solve this issue is to just use a `tabular` environment to arrange the label and the text field and nest this inside the other `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\TextFieldWithName}[1]{% label, field
    \begin{tabular}{ @{} l @{}}%
    \scriptsize #1 \\
    \TextField[name=#1]{}%
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    C & D & \multirow{2}*{E} \\ 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{F} 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \TextFieldWithName{C} & \TextFieldWithName{D} & \multirow{2}*{\TextFieldWithName{E}} \\ 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\TextFieldWithName{F}}
\end{tabular}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers, this seems to do the trick. However, I realised I need to do some more adjusting on the alignments. So I created another question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666959/align-hyperref-forms-in-table-environment).